# Measurability Question?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I assigned the following to a class I'm teaching and, to my embarrassment, I cannot come up with a solution.

> Let $(X,\mathcal B)$ be a measurable space and let $(f_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. Let $S=\{x\colon \text{$(f_n(x))$ contains a (strictly) increasing subsequence}\}$. Is $S$ necessarily measurable?

I believe the answer is "no", but I find myself ill-equipped to prove that a set is *not* measurable. Any suggestions?

Comment: If $X$ is a Polish space and $\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets, then $S$ looks like it's analytic and hence measurable with respect to any complete Borel measure.  I'm not sure that it's not Borel, though.

Comment: Just to be clear, we are assuming each $f_n:X\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry. Yes the functions map into $\mathbb R$ (and are measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal B$ on $X$). [Question edited to clarify this point]

Comment: Verifying Paul's comment: $x \in S$ iff $(\exists y \in [\omega]^{\omega})(\forall n)(f_{y(n)}(x) < f_{y(n+1)}(x))$. Here $y(n)$ denotes the $n$-th member of $y$. So $S$ is a projection of a Borel set and hence analytic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $A = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}^{\omega} : \{ x(n) : n < \omega \} \text{ is reverse well order as a suborder of rationals} \}$ is not Borel. Luzin and Sierpinski showed that it is in fact $\Pi_1^1$-complete - see Kechris, Classical descriptive set theory, page 213. Now let $f_n:\mathbb{Q}^{\omega} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $f_n(x) = x(n)$.

Comment: Also, as noted by Paul McKenney above, $\Sigma^1_1$ is an upper bound so this example is optimal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it clear that $x\in A$ if and only if my original condition holds?

Comment: No, $x \notin A$ iff $x \in S$ (so $S$ is $\Sigma^1_1$). This is because $\langle x(n) : n < \omega \rangle$ has a strictly increasing subsequence iff the set $\{x(n) : n < \omega\}$ is not a reverse well ordering.

Comment: Sorry. I'm still having trouble seeing the connection between not being a reverse well ordering; and having an increasing subsequence.

Comment: @anthonyquas: isn't it pretty direct from the definitions?  A reverse well ordering is a linear order with no infinite, strictly increasing subset.

Comment: @PaulMcKenney: In that case it is direct. I just didn't know the definition. Thanks!